# Android WebView not render of web page

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have some web page which open in WebView.

```
<body onload="window.location.href='htcmd:loaded';">
```

After load we open back url "htcmd:loaded" and  intercept  in code. 
Like this:

```
getWebView().getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getWebView().setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if ("htcmd:loaded".equals(url)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "htcmd:loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        getWebView().loadUrl("https://some.url");
```

On android 4.4.2 in first start all is well. But if I kill app and open after first run, web page not render. But if I tap on screen or change orientation web page appears. Where is problem?

SOLUTION: I have two hacks))) 
First: add a java script to web page:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='htcmd:loaded';},3000);">
```

Second: add code to web client:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        view.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
w.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
w.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);   
getWebView().getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
getWebView().setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           return (false);

    });
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String  failingUrl) {
                 Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
    getWebView().loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```